# Create a column where values are max of range of another column in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max

**My Problem**

I am trying to create a column in python where each value is equal to the max value of the last 64 rows of another column i.e. to find the rolling 64 day high of a stock.

I am currently using the following code, but it is really slow because of the loops. I want to try and re-do it without using loops. The dataset is simply the last closing price of a stock.

**Current Working Code**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

csv1 = pd.read_csv('vod_price.csv', delimiter = ',')
df = pd.DataFrame(csv1)

for x in range(1,65):
    df["3m high"].iloc[x]= df["PX_LAST"].iloc[:(x+1)].max()

for x in range(65,len(df.index)):
    df["3m high"].iloc[x]= df["PX_LAST"].iloc[(x-64):(x+1)].max()

df
```

**Attempt at Solution**

I have tried the following, but it just gives me the max of the whole column.

```
maxrange = df['PX_LAST'].between(df['PX_LAST'].shift(64),df['PX_LAST'])

df['3m high'] = df['PX_LAST'].loc[maxrange].max()
```

Does anyone know how I might be able to do it?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.rolling`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html):

```
df["3m high"] = df["PX_LAST"].rolling(64).max()
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply! I just tried that and it gives me NaN for the first 64 values. Is there a way to correct this? I was thinking something like this...

df['3m high'] = df['PX_LAST'].rolling(min(64,row(index))).max()

Comment: @pythonlearner13 - Use `df["3m high"] = df["PX_LAST"].rolling(64, min_periods=1).max()`